# Fail to download a file using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is a snippet of code I'm playing with:

```
$.get('http://www51.zippyshare.com/d/70229620/44835/data.json', function (data) {
console.log(data);
}).fail(function () {
console.log('I failed to download json')
});
```

Unfortunately, every time it fails to download that file and logs a message.

Why it doesn't download that file?

Comment: Cross-domain policy? What if you try JSONP?

Comment: What's your excact question? You don't want to log a message if it fails?

Comment: Maybe because the size of downloaded file is zero?

Comment: Edited my answer with some info on how to go about fixing this. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with cross-domain requests. In some browsers the security is set to a level where JSON (or other files) cannot be retrieved via javascript if the target file is on another domain as the domain you are currently on. In chrome I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www51.zippyshare.com/d/70229620/44835/data.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is therefore not allowed access.
```

A way to get around this is by using JSONP, which is designed to avoid this issue. You need control over the output of the requested file though. So in your case (getting a json file from zippyshare) this might get very complicated if the file in question is a dynamic file.

Here's a small JSONP example:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: "http://www51.zippyshare.com/d/70229620/44835/data.json",
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       console.log(json.data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

It is important that your data.json content is now wrapped into a function call, like this:

```
jsonCallback(
  {
    "data": "value"
  }
);
```

More information and explanation can be found here: http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Comment: Slick! Thanks for the code. I'll accept this answer. One question: before logging data in the console it outputs this: _Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/x-download: "http://www34.zippyshare.com/d/23896885/6013/data.json?callback=jsonCallback&_=1389009838017"_. What is that?

Comment: No problem! It means that the headers sent for the file were `application/x-download` but that the executing script is treating it as something else. The ajax request actually adds script tags into the HEAD section of the HTML document. Because the script tag encounters a strange mime-type in the requested file, the browser throws a warning. It shouldn't be that big of a deal, I don't think you can modify those headers sent by zippy anway...